# Model a simple plane into steps

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I'm trying to make some steps out of a rotated plane with some loop cuts.
A friend of mine did it in 3dsmax but I have no idea what tools I would use to make it in blender.

I'm trying to convert this
[image: starting mesh]

to this
[image: stairs mesh]

Here is a video of the process in 3ds max, the video is about 90 seconds.
[Simple Plane to Steps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uMDvPqU09Y&t=33s)

Comment: I really hate questions that make me go watch a video just to know what you are asking.

Comment: sorry but the process is about 60 seconds i thought it was the best way to show i'm new here

Comment: sorry. I should not of come off so mean. It is best to write questions that are self standing. You could add a couple of screen shots of the vid. But by no means are links to videos bad, just they should not make the entity of the question.

Comment: Questions on stackexchange last forever.  Videos or links to some external page may not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok what he is doing in 3ds max is doubling the edge loops (chamfer tool in max), then scaling the faces to make them flat.

We can do the exact same thing in blender.

Take this mesh. It is just a curved plane with some loop cuts. This will be our starting point to make some stairs/stadium seating.
[image: starting mesh]

1. Select every loop going up the stairs. Easy way to do that is with the *Mesh Select Mode* set to *Edge* select the bottom one, and then select edge rings. From the 3D view header *Select* > *Edge Rings*.
2. Bevel the selected edges <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. You want to start the bevel operator then type in a very small number, such as ".0000001" now press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That will have "doubled" all the edges in the middle.
3. Now switch to face selection, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>. That will invert the selection, giving us the selection we want. The bevel operator selects the newly created faces, so in this case the inverse is perfect.
4. Simply set the Pivot Point to *Individual Origins* and scale along the Z axis to 0. That will make the rows flat, thus making stairs.

[image: animated gif showing the whole process]