# Requesting help for answer to 'Model a simple plane into steps'

Tags: bevel

This is exactly what I want to do but I don't understand the answer:

[Model a simple plane into steps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101183/model-a-simple-plane-into-steps)

I'm in version 2.92 and don't understand which field to enter .0000001.  I also get lost in step 3 and 4.  If I switch to face selection my selected areas a gone.  I also didn't understand how to get into pivot point.  I'll go through the steps again.

Comment: try ctrl+I in edge mode before going to face mode

Comment: The "archimesh" add-on that comes with Blender already has a customizable stairs generator. I would recommend using that instead of self-modeling. Saves time and effort on your part.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the mouse clicks in the gif and I'm assuming he is doing a Scale Z (SZ).  I tried that but it doesn't do what his gif is doing.  I'll keep "archimesh" in mind if I can't figure this out but my blend already has planes already carefully positioned.

Comment: I think I got it now.  I had never used Pivot Point in the menu before. Changing it to Individual Origins allows the 'steps' to form as desired.

Answer (score 5):

Blender can do this in one, using the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> *Rip Fill* operator, with (in this case,) <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the direction of the extruded fill. (3DS can do this too, so some of the steps in the reference video to the other Q. are not strictly necessary)

There are a couple of gotchas.

- *Rip Fill* works only on edges between faces.
- The side of the edge-selection the mouse is on, before execution, matters. The new fill-face is extruded on the far side of the edge, with respect to the mouse.

With Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active', and working in an orthogonal view to ensure the mouse is on the right side of the loop selection:

[image]

Comment: i am too silly to reproduce your solution. If i press alt-v, it just pulls down the edge...no face fill. What am i doing wrong? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTswh.png

Comment: @Chris Nope, you're not silly. It's tricky. I think one of the gotchas gotcha. You have to be aware of where the mouse is when you call _Rip Fill_. Practice on a once-subdivided plane, observe the effect.. Ctrl-Z to wind back between tries, otherwise previous extrusions will confuse the whole issue.

Comment: really cool technique...i never realized what it is good for.... ;)