# How do I make steps like these? (Staircase)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

Here is what I want to steps to look like.

[image]

Basic steps and the bottom part should be one face.

What I did:

Created 2 planes and used array modifier for the steps.

1. Created one big edge for the bottom part. subdivided it and filled the face in between bottom edge and steps. -> Leads to some weird UV map and material looked weird
2. Extruding the steps down and using boolean, didnt work for some reason? (Only worked with subdivision modifier)
3. Extruding the step edges down. But now I got a "step-like" Edge on the bottom part. Then I merged the two vertex above another. But now I want to bevel the edges and for some reason on some parts I have double edges that go all the way down and not only like the red edge in the picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe array this? https://zupimages.net/up/22/22/quv9.jpg

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Check out :  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/224081/35559

Answer (score 4):

I'm a sucker for Geometry Nodes, so of course that's my suggestion. I used 3.3 Alpha for this,  but it should work with 3.2 Beta or even 3.1 with some adjustments.

### Modelling a Staircase with Geometry Nodes

Geometry Nodes are very good for a predictable objects like that. You can create a few settings inputs to reuse it in other situations and you're all set.

[image: staircase generator GN]

The full node tree.

[image: full nodes]

This is basically math and math and a bit more math. I created a curve triangle by deleting a vertex from a square, turned it into a mesh, cut a piece of it, duplicated, realigned and merged everything.

Here are readable close ups and what they do. Ignore the rounded edges, I forgot a bevel modifier on in some shots.

[image: 1 and 2]

[image: 3 and 4]

[image: 5 and 6]

[image: 07_1]
[image: 07_2]

You can bevel it by applying the geometry nodes, converting the "bottom" attribute to a vertex group and using that in the modifier.

[image: bevel]

Comment: Wow thank you. As I only did some geo node tutorials, I feel like I havent really learned geo nodes but only some recepes. I was sure there must be easy/obvious way to model those stairs but maybe I will try your approach. Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: Sadly, I am already stuck since I dont have the extrude mesh node

Comment: @patrick823 I find Geometry Nodes very useful for cases like this, architectural elements, because you'll only need to "model" the base asset once. That's odd about the **Extrude Mesh Node**, what version you're using? It already has an [entry in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/extrude_mesh.html), so it should be included in the latest stable release. **Named Attributes**, on the other hand, are in 3.2 beta.

Comment: @patrick823 Note: This node tree also serves as a tip for modelling the stairs in the regular way. Start with a square, remove an edge, adjust height and depth to match steps' specs, extrude it to staircase's width. Then you can use an array mod with relative Z, Y 1 and your steps number, apply it, extrude the bottom on Z, remove useless loops and do a boolean with the floor and top to remove triangular tips (or just sink it in another objects).